# Shoud this site focus on reviwing peoples code or how to review code

Tags: discussion

I think that code review, especially peer review, is essential in improving quality, decreasing maintenance costs, etc. So, should this site strive to help people promote this philosophy or merely provide free code reviews?

(I think both, but focus on the first part).

Thoughts?

Comment: I guess the result should be used in the "what not to ask" faq since this will come up often

Answer (score 21):

**The Code Review Stack Exchange is for sharing code** from projects you're working on to get peer feedback and review. This site is **not for discussions about the *discipline and practice* of code reviews**.

If you see any questions *about* conducting code reviews (best practices, techniques, etc), those questions should be closed and the author kindly directed to the [Programmers Stack Exchange](http://programmers.stackexchange.com) site.

Comment: Agreed. It would help if we had an explicit migration path (right now, there's no "Belongs on Programmers.SE" reason, only "Off Topic")

Comment: @Inaimathi: Migration paths cannot be set up until the site is out of beta. In the meantime, properly closing and kindly asking the author to redirect their question is a matter of community self-moderation. That's a big part of defining and developing this site.

Comment: Thanks for restateing that fact Robert, i read through most of meta and i haven't understood that until now. (Mostly because i misread the top rated answer on this question).

Answer (score 16):

I agree that both aspects are important. Although, one could learn how to code review by simply reading through this site. It seems that questions about code reviews are better asked on Programmers.SE.

Comment: This is what I assumed; questions about programming/related practices => Programmers.SE (or possible SO, I guess). "please review this code" => CodeReview.SE

Comment: I guess it is inevitable that there will be a lot of overlap between CR.se and both P.se and SO.

Answer (score 9):

Based on a quick review of [Code Review site proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/11464?phase=definition), I think both are legit.

Comment: Possibly too legit.:)

Comment: I'd agree.  Since the purpose is code review, I think it would benefit users to at the same time here, learn how to review code.  Likely you won't see many questions after the initial "how do I review code", but at least when they're starting a new post, they get to see the link right there to the question already asked.

Comment: we seem to do a dismal job at telling folks what a good review is, or how to write one.